# Issues when trying to reach the controller with a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, razor

So, I have a view based on a model that depend from a controller.

Inside that view I have a partial view for a modal, inside that modal the user have to give some information and then submit. I've called it `_ModalContent` and it's should depend on the same controller but when I try to make this inside the controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyView(ParentModel model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
        UserInformationViewModel info = model.UserInformationViewModel;
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
        var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");
        BsonDocument objDocument = new BsonDocument {
            {"Nom",info.NomUser},
            {"Prenom",info.PrenomUser},
            {"Email",info.EmailUser},
            {"Telephone",info.TelephoneUser},
            };

        collection.InsertOne(objDocument);
        }
        return View("_ModalContent");
    }
```

I never reach the breakpoint. So nothing is saved in my database. Can't figure out why !

**RAZOR CODE**

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" style="height:650px;width:775px; text-align: center;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Informations</h4>
                    <p><b>You have to fill your informations</b></p>
                </div>
                @Html.Partial("_ModalContent")
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**RAZOR CODE 2**

```
    @model ParentModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreerGarantie", "Garantie", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1" }))
    {
    <div id ="userinput" class="form-panel-modify">
    <div class="form-horizontal style-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NomUser, new {@class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label"})
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NomUser, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.PrenomUser, new {@class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label"})
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.PrenomUser, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EmailUser, new {@class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label"})
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EmailUser, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.TelephoneUser, new {@class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label"})
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.TelephoneUser, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:25px;">
   <input type="submit" disabled="true" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#48bcb4;border-color: #48bcb4;">
</div>
 }
```

**AJAX :**

```
     $('#submit').click(function () {

    var model=$('#form1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/ActionName',
        type: 'POST',
        data: model,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
  )};
```

Comment: Show the razor code where you are adding partial view.

Comment: I've added it, tell me if you need something else

Comment: Also add the razor code from partial view

Comment: it's done, something else ?

Comment: Where's the `Model` definition in the `PartialView`?

Comment: Where is form submit button in your view or partial view. I dont see any form submit button. Without that controller will not be fired

Comment: Sorry, it's on the second razor code

Comment: `disabled="true"` would prevent the submit to happen.

Comment: it's disabled until all the fields are filled. I'm using a script for that

Comment: Better call javascript method for validating like

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return beforeSubmit();"/>`
and return false from the method when you do not want to hit the controller ;otherwise return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap form submit button in [Html.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) and add proper controller name and action method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyView", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)
{
    <div style="margin-top:25px;">
       <input type="submit" disabled="true" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#48bcb4;border-color: #48bcb4;">
   </div>
}
```

**Edit :** Ajax Approach

```
$('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/MyView',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,      
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
)};
```

Comment: Not working, i think it's because my view where the partial is called is already wrap inside a Html.BeginForm

Comment: You need to add one more `@Html.BeginForm` for partial view submit button.

Comment: Yes i added it like you said, but nothing happen. And in my view the partial call is wrapped inside a @Html.BeginForm, i think it make a conflict no ?

Comment: It's really strange i'm not reaching the controller :/

Comment: Can you try calling it using ajax. See my update in my answer

Comment: How i put this ? I've never used ajax

Comment: I've made an edit : @using (Html.BeginForm("CreerGarantie", "Garantie", FormMethod.Post, Model.UserInformationViewModel)) but now it return an error like this : System.NullReferenceException

Comment: I-ve deleted my partial and put everything in the same view now it works !

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Ajax call then when you are doing POST model then you have to serialize that model

First you have to wrap your .cshtml code in form tag like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post,new { @id="form1" })
{
   // your cshtml code here

}
```

on submit button click event

```
$('#submit').click(function () {

    var model=$('#form1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/ActionName',
        type: 'POST',
        data: model,  
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
 });
```

Note : if you are using button type="submit". Please use button type="button". For ajax Post request.

Comment: do i need to pu ajax inside script balise ?

Comment: yup.. if you are using partial view then first ensure that the id of that form doesn't exist anywhere in that rendered view. You can try with put this script code in that partial view.

Comment: Ok, but i'm getting an error, like a ) unexpected but where

Comment: have u used '$(function(){    });' this tag before ajax call

Comment: please update last line )}   with });   i have updated my ajax code please see last line.

Comment: do i replace the }); by )} ?

Comment: No ... My controller is fine, inside my action is called _ModalContent and returns a partial view, also made a verification if it's empty or not. The only way to get an error is not to use ajax and put this param "Model.UserInformationModel" to my Html.BeginForm. Also i've put a breakpoint on my controller and i never reach the action. About the button do i need to change it ? if it's submit type then put a button type instead ?

Comment: No problem to return partial view from ActionResult . you need to use PARENT model as a parameter in actionResult parameter then it will be called. now u r using child model inside a model.  The serialize funtion will serialize ur base model not the child model. u can check once

Comment: I have my parent model in parameter now, i mean i have made this change

Comment: in RAZOR CODE 2 u r using child model

Comment: Yes, so what i have to use my parent model ? because in controller code i've made an edit if you want to see. I edited the RAZOR 2

Comment: u have to pass parent model parameter in actionresult. then u can access ur child model as parentmodel.childmodel.fieldname

Comment: it's not working, i think this is all because the partial

Comment: inRAZOR CODE 2 please change button type="button"  not submit... your code is working for me..

Comment: it's working but i did it another way, i've pulled out the partial view code to my view

Comment: if it can be a solution then marked it as answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Ajax call like

```
$('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/MyView',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,      
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
)};
```

The data parameter should be created with similar structure as your model is.
Data will be send in

```
 "JSON.stringify({your javascriptmodelobject})"
```

this format

Comment: I'd like to do it whithout ajax, but i found very strange that i'm not reaching the controller. Maybe something with route ?

Comment: Add an Html.beginform then

Comment: With the Html.BeginForm it's not reachning the controller... Only i i give a parameter Model.UserInformationViewModel and that gives me an error